# Can I replace null values in returned rows in QuestDB?

Tags: analytics, questdb

Some aggregate queries are returning null values, is there a way to handle this?

```sql
select time, avg(temp_f) from sensor_data sample by 1h
```

If some records are missing, can the aggregate be set to something other than null?

Answer (score 1):

- If your dataset has gaps of time and is missing entire records for a certain duration, you can use `FILL()`. You can choose a fill strategy, such as `LINEAR` for interpolation, `PREV` for filling with the previous value, or you can specify constants. This will include new rows in the returned response where there were gaps:

  ```sql
  SELECT time, avg(temp_f) 
  FROM sensor_data
  SAMPLE BY 1h FILL(50);
  ```
- If your dataset has records for a certain period, but a sensor was sending `null` instead of a value, you can use `coalesce()` to specify how `null` should be handled. No new rows are returned and a default is set for null values:

  ```sql
  SELECT time, coalesce(avg(temp_f), 50) 
  FROM sensor_data
  SAMPLE BY 1h;
  ```

For more information, see the [FILL keyword documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/sql/fill/) and for coalesce(), see the [conditional functions documentation](https://questdb.io/docs/reference/function/conditional/) pages.